# JDBCAttribute finder

Tags: wso2

Any idea how to plug JDBCAttribute finder in WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0? Any reference would also be helpful

There are online materials which point to lower versions of IS but I'm looking for 4.0.0 in particular

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the entitlement.properties as follows.

```
PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.1=org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.pip.DefaultAttributeFinder
PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.2=org.wso2.identity.samples.entitlement.pip.jdbc.JDBCAttributeFinder
```

Also make the class 
public class JDBCAttributeFinder extends AbstractPIPAttributeFinder

Remember to add

```
@Override
public String getModuleName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

in this class